# mkfifo read and write error

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes

I am not understanding what am I doing wrong, kindly help me in pointing out. I am just giving here the input what i am trying do exactly in the program so that it's easy to understand. I have created 3 named pipes and writing the string `"Hello, world!"` to the 1st named pipe `myfifo.example`. Now I am reading the same named pipe and trying to copy the  data to the 2nd named pipe `cmyfifo11`. This read and write is not happenning. It's not even printing lines **(1)** and **(2)**. Can any body please correct me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int n, fd1, fd2;
    int pid,status;
    char    line[30]="Hello, world!\n";
    if (mkfifo("myfifo.example", 0660)<0)
        perror("Cannot create fifo");

    if (mkfifo("cmyfifo11", 0660)<0)
        perror("Cannot create fifo1");
    if (mkfifo("cmyfifo22", 0660)<0)
        perror("Cannot create fifo2");
    if((fd1= open("myfifo.example", O_RDWR))<0)
        perror("Cannot open fifo to write");  

    if ( (pid = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork error");
    else if(pid==0){
        int z=write(fd1,line,strlen(line));
        printf("Write is done on myfifo.example\n");
        printf("CHILD PROCESS 1\n");
        fd2=open("cmyfifo11",O_RDWR);
        printf("Value of fd2=%d\n",fd2);
        if(fd2<0)
            printf("Cannot open cmyfifo11\n");
        printf("Reading\n");
        if((n=read(fd1,line,z))<0) /* Read and write is not happening */
            perror("Read error");
        printf("Value of n:%d with line %s\n",n);--->(1)
            int x=write(fd2,line,n);-------------->(2)
            printf("%d\n",x);

    }

    else if(pid>0){ printf("Parent area with %d\n",getpid());sleep(300);}
    printf("Common area\n");

    return 0;
}
```

ouput is

```
Write is done on myfifo.example
CHILD PROCESS 1
Value of fd2=4
Reading
Parent area with 349
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a segmentation fault because you forgot to pass `line` to `printf()`

```
printf("Value of n:%d with line %s\n",n)
```

should be

```
printf("Value of n:%d with line %s\n",n, line);
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot Alper,i was digging this thing from morning onwards,Thanks for pointing out.Its  working fine now.